# CakePHP custom route pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I would like to format my URL like so:

`/news/index/page:2`

to

`/news/2`

I would like to achieve this result by using as less code as possible (perhaps only from routes.php?), without modifying how the PaginatorHelper behaves.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
// Add this to /app/config/routes.php
Router::connect('/news/:page', array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! One more thing, though...I would like to display `news` instead of `news/1`, so I won't have two URLs pointing to the same page...How can I do this from `router.php`? And, is `:page` a default route element or a custom one? If it is a custom one, how come it doesn't need to be "explained" in the third parameter of the `Router::connect()` method?

Comment: `:page` is named attribute which is automatically parsed by `Pagination` class, This class look for `$this->params[page]` no matter how you pass it. This might be interesting for you http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes ... cheers

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Regarding the `news/1` to `news` issue, do you have any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: There's no configuration to control this argument. You have to hack pagination helper if your really want to do that. Recommended solution would be just link this page with `<a href="/news">` (*default page value is 1*) and let the paginater append numbers as people navigate through pages.