# Pagination and sort - Plugin not working - CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, sorting, plugins, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have created a plugin called movies, I have used custom routes.
I have used pagination limit as '5'.

The first page is fine, but when I click on next or numbers. Those things doesn't works.

URL: `something.com/movieslist/2`

`my Plugin/Movies/Config/routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/movieslist', array('plugin' => 'Movies', 'controller' => 'Movies', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/movieslist/:page', array('plugin' => 'Movies', 'controller' => 'Movies', 'action' => 'index'));
```

`my action code: Plugin/Movies/Controller/MoviesController.php`

```
public function index() {
        $this->Movie->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate = array('limit'=>5);
        $this->set('movies', $this->paginate());
    }
```

`my view file code: Plugin/Movies/View/Movies/index.ctp`

Same one from cakebake console. No changes made here.

Even the sort doesn't works :(
I'm tiered of searching my problems in many places :(

I had previously getting error in links itself and I fixed this after seeing this page:
[CakePHP custom route pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033633/cakephp-custom-route-pagination)

Links are fixed but the links doesn't works. Pls don't down vote, I'm struggling from long time.

I'm using `cakephp 2.0` version.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I'd swap the order of the router rules, since cakephp stops after the first match found. While the "/movieslist/:page" one will match a url with a page, it only does so for the named parameter `page`. Without it a url of the form "/movielist/2", might be interpreted as a link to "/movielist" with a normal parameter "2", hence the first router rule triggers.

If that does not work you can always just manually set the named `page` parameter. `paginate` just looks to see if it is set, but does not care if cakephp automagically figured it out from the url or if you do it yourself.

```
public function index($myPage=1) {
    $this->Movie->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array('limit'=>5);
    $this->params["page"] = $myPage;
    $this->set('movies', $this->paginate());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mtsvetkov, Actually I changed all the files from plugin to the main controller folder. Now its working fine. Anyways I will give it a try and let you know weather its working or not :)